# In distribution tests, why do we assume that any distribution is true unless proven otherwise?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, statistical-significance

To me, as a non-statistician with barely a basic understanding of statistics, this does not make sense. Why do you assume whatever distribution (e.g. Weibull or Normal) we test is true unless proven otherwise?!

Isn't the null hypothesis should be the opposite of whatever we are assuming?

When we use Mann-Whitney, for example, to see whether or not two samples come from the same distribution, and since it is often assumed that a difference exists, it makes sense to have a null hypothesis stating that they are not different unless proven otherwise.

I assume that the answer to my question lies on the general rule ["All null hypotheses include an equal sign in them"]. But I still do not know why and I am still not convinced!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to take the normal distribution as an example here. We have two hypotheses:

$H_0$ The random variable is normally distributed

$H_1$ The random variable is not normally distributed

If we want to test $H_0$ we can assume the hypothesis and compare the data against the expected results from a normally distributed variable. If we see unlikely data then that suggests that $H_0$ is false.

If we want to test $H_1$ we start by assuming that the random variable is not normally distributed. So what do we compare our data to? It could have a uniform distribution or an exponential distribution or anything else. We have no expected results for the data because the hypothesis doesn't make any predictions about what data we should get.

It's not possible to reject $H_1$ so we can never take it as our default hypothesis.